# ClassNotFindException while running Android sample EffectiveNavigation for older platform

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-support-library

I am running the sample from [Implementing Effective Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html) - EffectiveNavigation.zip - which demonstrates some swipe views with tabs in an activity. It runs fine on a newer platform such as 4.2.2 (API17).

Then I want to support older platforms such as 2.3.3 (API10) too, so I lower the minSdkVersion to 4:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

I do include the support libraries in one of the following ways:

1. by the book: V4 [Support Library Setup - without resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res)
2. or by the book: V7 [Support Library Setup - with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)
3. or right-click in project ->Android Tools->Add Support Library

Anyway, when I run the app on a 2.3.3 device, this ambiguous runtime exception occurs as in the listing below.

Before rushing in that has been asked before please note: my problem is I can't run it on older devices such as 2.3.3 - but runs fine on newer devices such as 4.2.2.

I deleted, reimported and rebuilt and rerun with various changed settings on various emulators. It just doesn't run on older devices (my purpose is using tabs and swipe views in older devices).

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.effectivenavigation/com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.effectivenavigation-1.apk]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.effectivenavigation-1.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Comment: Just tried in Android Studio. Same problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally solved, after one day and one night wasted!

Most of the problem was that the app was also implementing an ActionBar and that needed more migration effort. I had to change some other bits to use the support libraries (v4 and v7), mostly:

- everything from [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) (see V7 with resources + using APIs)
- plus everything from [Chris's video about AppCompat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc)
- plus be careful to examine every error and warning in Eclipse

Code changes in Java files:

```
<< import android.app.ActionBar;
<< import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
---
>> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
>> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


<< public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
---
>> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


<< final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
---
>> final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Changes in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<< <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
---
>> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<< android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
---
>> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

It's not about cleaning up and rebuilding the project, though you may do so if it makes you feel better.

Now I have ActionBar and Tabs with SwipeViews on my 2.3.3 Android.

Google is putting so much emphasis on these backports, and I have to use them, too bad there isn't some more clear and complete documentation about it. I even have troubles finding that video myself unless I refer to YouTube history - don't even know how I found it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use swipes with tabs below  **Android Api 11** 
that is Honeycomb.

So Manifest file will look like

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```